# Problema ao estilizar um placeholder com base em uma classe em CSS

Tags: css, css3

Estou tentando fazer com que eu possa ter diversos tipos de placeholder com base em uma classe definida assim:

```
.red,
.red::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.red:-moz-placeholder,
.red::-moz-placeholder,
.red:-ms-input-placeholder{
    color:red
}
```

O problema é que se eu defino dessa forma ele não funciona, não consigo entender porque não posso estilizar inúmeros elementos junto do CSS quando se trata do placeholder... alguém tem uma luz?

**EDIT**

Eu percebi que se eu declarar cada seletor separado ele funciona, mas não fica "bonito" de se ver quando se está criando os códigos. Assim:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}

    .red::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: red;
    }

    .red:-moz-placeholder {
        color: red;
    }

    .red::-moz-placeholder {
        color: #fff !important;
    }

    .red:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: #fff !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que bom que conseguiu resolver o problema sozinho.

A única solução que encontrei até hoje foi utilizando esse método de declarar as regras separadamente.

Acredito que isso seja necessário porque quando o browser não reconhece um seletor ele ignora toda a regra. Portanto quando o webkit não reconhece o seletor do firefox ele ignora a regra CSS, e o oposto também é verdadeiro.

Comment: que saco heim? fazer o que né...